# How to get the day number with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have this function below that gets the Day, month and year, but I would like it to also show the number. Right now it gives me: "February 2018 Saturday". I would like it to say: "February 2018 Saturday 17". The number is for the days date.

function:

```
   window.onload = function() {
var date = new Date();

document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {weekday: 'numeric', weekday: 'long', month: 'long', year: 'numeric'});
}
```

html:

```
   <div id="date"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

can try this

```
var event = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));

var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

console.log(event.toLocaleDateString( options));
```

Comment: Probably should avoid using `event` as a variable name for your date

Answer (score 0):

Is missing the option `day: 'numeric'`.  However, the format changes.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var date = new Date();

  document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    weekday: 'numeric',
    weekday: 'long',
    month: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric'
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="date"> </div>
```

Comment: thanks! But why am I not allowed to change the order? Like "17 Saturday, February, 2018"

Comment: @Alison because of locale `en-US`

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var date = new Date();

  document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    weekday: 'numeric',
    weekday: 'long',
    month: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric'
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="date"> </div>
```